# In R, how do I add a string of text to column names?

Tags: r, string, rename

I want to add a string of text at the end of the column names in my data frame. How do I do this?

Example data (where I want to change column names `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` to `Atext`, `Btext`, `Ctext`, `Dtext`, `Etext`):

```
df <- structure(list(User_ID = 1:4, A = c(0.815353067, 0.698314902, 0.774619233, 0.949620322),
                      B = c(0.684046246, 0.427028078, 0.579449798, 0.977426626),
                      C = c(0.101562005, 0.943064479, 0.19946195, 0.70068721),
                      D = c(0.525384365, 0.638082727, 0.651924335, 0.112375646), 
                      E = c(0.415664129, 0.006406548, 0.85036104, 0.510504667)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep` to find the letter name columns, along with `paste` to concatenate the string `text` to the end:

```r
names.change <- grep("^[A-Z]+$", names(df))
names(df)[names.change] <- paste0(names(df)[names.change], "text")
df

  User_ID     Atext     Btext     Ctext     Dtext       Etext
1       1 0.8153531 0.6840462 0.1015620 0.5253844 0.415664129
2       2 0.6983149 0.4270281 0.9430645 0.6380827 0.006406548
3       3 0.7746192 0.5794498 0.1994619 0.6519243 0.850361040
4       4 0.9496203 0.9774266 0.7006872 0.1123756 0.510504667
```

Comment: Ahh I see. This is the second time in 24 hours I have needed regular expressions, which I have never come across before. It took me forever to find a solution for something seemingly so simple (and I got nowhere). Thank you very much!

Comment: @aspark2020 You don't necessarily need regex here.  For example, if you know the numerical indices of the `A`, `B`, etc. columns in your data frame, you may simply subset.  I assumed you don't know this, so I used a more generic approach with `grep`.

Comment: True, but I like the fact that your solution is more generalisable.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer it in a one-liner with `dplyr::rename_with`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rename_with(~paste0(., "Text"), grep("^[A-Z]$", names(.)))
```

Output:

```
  User_ID     AText     BText     CText     DText       EText
1       1 0.8153531 0.6840462 0.1015620 0.5253844 0.415664129
2       2 0.6983149 0.4270281 0.9430645 0.6380827 0.006406548
3       3 0.7746192 0.5794498 0.1994619 0.6519243 0.850361040
4       4 0.9496203 0.9774266 0.7006872 0.1123756 0.510504667
```

Comment: @U12-Forward: Friendly notice: Here is a suggestion with `rename_with` as `rename_at` is superseded <https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_all.html> `library(dplyr)   
rename_with(df, ~paste0("text", .), 2:6)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution without `grepl`:

```
colnames(df)[-1] <- paste0(colnames(df)[-1], "text")
```

output:

```
  User_ID     Atext     Btext     Ctext     Dtext       Etext
1       1 0.8153531 0.6840462 0.1015620 0.5253844 0.415664129
2       2 0.6983149 0.4270281 0.9430645 0.6380827 0.006406548
3       3 0.7746192 0.5794498 0.1994619 0.6519243 0.850361040
4       4 0.9496203 0.9774266 0.7006872 0.1123756 0.510504667
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also use `rename_with`. But i think we can use the `.cols` argument,  so we can include a selection helper before the call to `rename_with`, obviating the need for `grep`.

```
df %>% rename_with(.cols=matches('[A-E]'), ~paste0(.x, 'text'))
```

If the selected columns are consistently A-Z, the selection can be even simpler:

```
df %>% rename_with(~paste0(.x, 'text'), A:E)
```

**output**

```
  User_ID     Atext     Btext     Ctext     Dtext       Etext
1       1 0.8153531 0.6840462 0.1015620 0.5253844 0.415664129
2       2 0.6983149 0.4270281 0.9430645 0.6380827 0.006406548
3       3 0.7746192 0.5794498 0.1994619 0.6519243 0.850361040
4       4 0.9496203 0.9774266 0.7006872 0.1123756 0.510504667
```